Anchoring or moving thumb at the back of the neck? Guitar question
I am learning Acoustic Guitar. Let's take spider exercise at the first four frets as an example. Some people say that, your thumb should stay still at the back, being around at the level of second fret. For me, I have it hard to reach the fourth fret when my thumb is closer to the head stock, and hard to reach to the first fret when thumb is closer to the body of the guitar. So, i need to move my thumb. but this time I lose some consistency between changing frets. For finger stretching I really tried my best. Is keeping the thumb still the best practice?

I recommend clarifying whether you're learning the classical style or rock/jazz/folk. I also suggest posting a photo showing where your thumb is when you're starting the spider exercise.

We're all built differently, and for some, keeping the thumb still is an option. For most, sliding it up and down makes more sense, and it's more comfortable. There is no 'rule' saying it ought to be static, so do what you have to do. Just do it smoothly.
And - never start this sort of exercise (rather like playing barre chords) at the head end of the guitar. The middle  of the neck where the frets are closer, is always better - unless you have a guitar which is so badly set up, the action gets worse the further towards the dusty end you venture.

Second fret is not that close to the head stock.  It might help if you posted pics of your hand position.  While Tim is correct that we are all built differently we should also avoid using it as an excuse to not develop good techniques.  Everything feels strange to a beginner and in time, and with proper guidance these things can be overcome.  What do you mean by a "spider exercise"?  If you just mean some variant of a chromatic pattern then try it at the 7th fret and work your way down.  You will eventually be able to reach all 4 frets in the first position.

I think the spider exercise is something like the following: starting on the 6th string, play frets 1 then 3, 5th string 2 and 4, (4) 1-3, (3) 2-4, (2) 1-3 (1) 2-4. Then you might move up 1 fret and reverse it to come back, or some variation on that idea.

One spider exercise is say between frets 5 and 8, fret 5 6th string, fret 6 5th st., fret 7 6th st., fret 8 5th st. using the ofpf arrangement. it's probably not the only one - there are hundreds of permutations available, all based on ofpf. Best start around my suggested 5>8 fret, where the stretch is a lot less.  more simplistic one is chromatic scale playing, simply going up each string one fret at a time, 4 fingers per string.

So basically some type of finger permutation of 1, 2, 3, 4 on consecutive frets.

Yes, any mix of ofpf!

'Second fret is not that close to the headstock'. It's only two frets away - couldn't be a lot closer!

Make sure to have only the tip of the thumb on the back of the neck and make sure your thumb has a slight inwards bend or is at most straight. This will make the thumb a fulcrum that allows your hand to move freely, quickly and cover a lot of space. You will often find famous pop music guitarist playing with either the neck in the palm of the hand or with the thumb really bend outward. This heavily limits the ability of the fingers and the hand to move an reach positions without shifting.
If you look at the musicians who play like this — they tend to stick to quite basic playing. It will also allow you to place your fingers more precisely and to put more pressure at the right points, making your playing cleaner. Also it will in the long term avoid problems with the joints.
I would advice to look at classical guitar players. On electric and acoustic the answer to this problem is a cheat: Narrower necks. Narrow necks makes it easier to play the guitar even if your technique is sloppy. On classical guitar you have wide necks and you have to use good technique, else you won’t get very far. But conversely, even if you do not play classical guitar is can still teach you a lot about good technique.
I think even with small hands with proper technique you should be able to reach 1st to 4th fret. If you absolutely cannot you can try doing the technique a few frets higher up. Because it is not supposed to be a shifting exercise, but an exercise for finger coordination and agility.
But as I said, with proper technique you’ll most likely be able to do it. Remember, it is not about stretching you fingers, but about using your thumb as a fulcrum to move your whole hand. And maybe some stretching of fingers.
